# Delete specific record data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete all my artists that have not recorded a paticular genre; namely, jazz titles. I formulated the following query:

```
select * from artists ar
join titles ti on ti.artistid = ar.artistid
where ti.genre != 'jazz';
```

I believe this data to be artists who have not recorded a jazz title. Also, I am unsure as to the command to delete this data.

My Artists table is as follows:

```
Artists
-------
ArtistID, ArtistName, City, Region
```

My Titles table is as follows:

```
Titles
------
TitleID, ArtistID, Title, StudioID, Genre
```

I have also tried:

```
delete artists
from artists ar
inner join
titles ti on ti.artistid = ar.artistid where ti.genre != 'jazz';
```

The SQL Query Engine throws me an error stating: ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'artists' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: Your first query is wrong. It lists all artists who have recorded a non-jazz title. So it will list an artist who has recorded classical, even if he has also recorded jazz.

Comment: Why `select ar.artistid, ar.artistname` as opposed to `select *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query should be:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM artists a
LEFT JOIN titles t ON t.artistid = a.artistid AND t.genre = 'jazz'
WHERE t.artistid IS NULL
```

The corresponding `DELETE` is:

```
DELETE a.*
FROM artists a
LEFT JOIN titles t ON t.artistid = a.artistid AND t.genre = 'jazz'
WHERE t.artistid IS NULL
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. I know this is correct because I receive an empty set after running the delete query. I will accept this answer (and all other answers of similar nature) as stackoverflow allows.

Comment: @Barmar At first glance your DELETE, I though `a.*` is a mistake. But I was wrong. It worked well. from time to time I forgot Syntax for multiple table delete. But very easy! first Test SELECT query, then just replace SELECT to DELETE. Thanks!